# Run batch script on all files in a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-scripting

I have a folder receiving 'calculations' files daily. Sometimes a few files arrive. I want to execute a batch script on all of them in a loop. Files may have different name but may contain three extensions only: .ta, .tb, .tc.

I am trying to run a batch script on all of them, rename the files so that they contain a timestamp and move to archive folder. I have tried multiple combinations of the below but I can't figure it out:

```
cd C:\test\files

FOR %%x IN (*.ta, *.tb, *.tca) DO (
    call C:\test\batches\combine.bat
    move %%x "C:\test\archive\calculations.txt-%date:/=-%_%time::=-%"
)
```

In the above case, combine.bat is not executed properly and the file is not moved. However, when I run it as follows it is launching combine.bat and moving the file. But if I have two files, combine.bat is executed on both but the second one is not moved to archive folder:

```
FOR /R C:\test\files %%x IN (*.ta, *.tb, *.tca) DO (
    call C:\test\batches\combine.bat
    move %%x "C:\test\archive\calculations.txt-%date:/=-%_%time::=-%"
)
```

The problem is that there are other folders under C:\test\files and I want the 'combine.bat' to run for this specific path only and not for any sub-folders. Is it failing because I have changed directory in the beginning to C:\test\files and the loop is then calling to another directory?

Appreciate you help.

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense to me as I do not understand why `combine.bat` is being called with no arguments every single time a file is returned at `DO`. Can you please provide the content of `combine.bat` and explain what the code is intended to achieve?

Comment: The `combine.bat` is supposed to go through the files in C:\test\files, find proper data and load it into the DB. I am quite new to windows scripts but looking into it now, I am thinking it should be `call C:\test\batches\combine.bat %%x` as the .bat file should be executed on every %%x file in the loop.

Comment: To explain further, `combine.bat` takes the file, searchers for proper data and loads it into the DB. Then we should have the file moved to archive folder and a new loop should start where `combine.bat` would process next file.

Comment: You're not `call`ing `combine.bat` with `"%%~x"` or `"%%dpx"` as an argument, so it's not working with any of those returned metavariables. You should still post the content of `combine.bat`, or at least make sure that it accepts an input argument and does not finish with an explicit `exit` command.

Comment: When you say it takes any arguments you give it, is that multiple or one only, for instance why not just run `C:\test\batches\combine.bat *.ta, *.tb, *.tca` with a recursive option. Also does `combine.bat` end with an `Exit` command or is it possible that there's an unbalanced `setlocal` in it, and how does it accept those arguments? If you are not willing to provide the code, and we're not willing to guess, then it seems we're at an impasse.

Comment: The combine.bat will accept any argument that is provided, it does not have restrictions on file type or name. It is java application that takes any file that is provided and does the conversion. 

What you are saying is that I should use my `%%x` argument for every query in the loop?

`cd C:\test\files

FOR %%x IN (*.ta, *.tb, *.tca) DO (
    call "%%x" C:\test\batches\combine.bat
    move %%x "C:\test\archive\calculations.txt-%date:/=-%_%time::=-%"
)`

I thought that once I specify `x` variable, the loop will go through all queries and execute them on `x` variable.

Comment: If you're not willing to provide the content of `combine.bat` and you will not answer the questions I've asked about how it accepts arguments, what type of arguments it accepts, whether it has `setlocal` statements and how it ends. You're just going to have to try `Call`ing the script using, `%%x`, `"%%x"`, `%%~dpx`, `%%~dpx` or whatever metavariable you think you need.